# Pythagorean CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV with 5 columns A, B, foo, bar, and baz. I would like to create a 6th column C such that `C = sqrt( A^2 + B^2)`

I have tried pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv(‘filename’)
C = df[‘A’]**2 + df[‘B’] **2
```

I don’t know how to take the square root of that column, or how to add it back to the original data frame. Also, this is taking a long time (a lot of data) any ideas on how to speed it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's start with the pythagorean theorem. You're on the right track with:

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

To take the square root of something, you can use `math.sqrt`. Remember, the square root of something is also the same as putting it to the `1/2` power. So, this leaves you with two options:

```
from math import sqrt
def pythagorean(a, b):
    return sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

```
# without math.sqrt
def pythagorean(a, b):
    return (a**2 + b**2)**0.5
```

Although you have not specified *where* you want column `C` to be located, I am assuming you want it to be located after columns `A` and `B`. You can use `pandas.insert` to insert a column at a specific location, and then use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to create a column from calculations on other columns:

```
df.insert(
    loc=2,
    column="C",
    value=df.apply(lambda row: pythagorean(row["A"], row["B"]), axis=1)
)
```

Which outputs:

```
   A  B         C  foo  bar  baz
0  3  4  5.000000    x    y    z

[100000 rows x 6 columns]
[Finished in 3.3s]
```

Answer (score 1):

without pandas

```
import math

with open('data.csv') as f:
    new_lines = []
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if idx > 0:
            fields = line.split(',')
            a = int(fields[0])
            b = int(fields[1])
            c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
            new_lines.append(fields)
            new_lines[-1].append(str(c))
with open('data_with_c.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(lines[0] + ',C\n')
    for line in new_lines:
        f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

data.csv

```
A,B,foo,bar,baz
12,34,z,z,z
1,7,z,z,z
11,4,z,z,z
8,6,k,k,k
```

data_with_c.csv

```
A,B,foo,bar,baz,C
12,34,z,z,z,36.05551275463989
1,7,z,z,z,7.0710678118654755
11,4,z,z,z,11.704699910719626
8,6,k,k,k,10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The @gmdev solution works OK but if time is a concern in your case, I strongly recommand you to use the numpy functions to do vectorized calculations, instead of looping on rows :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(1.,4.,1.),'B':np.arange(6.,9.,1.)})
df['C']=np.sqrt(np.power(df['A'],2.)+np.power(df['B'],2.))
print(df)
```

Gives

```
     A    B         C
0  1.0  6.0  6.082763
1  2.0  7.0  7.280110
2  3.0  8.0  8.544004
```